# Is "expert system" now an obsolete/unpopular term?

Tags: terminology, artificial-intelligence, expert-systems

While doing research on expert systems, I notice that it is rare to see this term used in the last 20 years. For example, a recent paper was:

- Wang, Hao, Naiyan Wang, and Dit-Yan Yeung. "Collaborative deep learning for recommender systems." Proceedings of the 21th ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining. ACM, 2015.

Not only is the term *expert system* used nowhere in the paper, but a survey paper that referred to this paper does not mention expert systems anywhere either, even though that is exactly what the paper describes.

Apparently, the term "expert system" is now gauche and we now should not use it anymore.

Nevertheless, there seems to be no term to replace it. So, for example in the above cited paper the word used is a "recommender system" which is a joke. I am not going to use such an ungrammatical term to replace expert system. Is there a better term to replace "expert systems"?

Comment: I can not comment on this specific paper, but I've seen a general trend to change the terminology every decade or so (or less), especially in the most applied areas. I would not be surprised if that is driven by the need to present research as newer in grant applications, etc.

Comment: If AI didn't change the labels every few years, people would catch on to that its path is littered with broken promises.</snark>